# How to sort results of Find statement by date?

Tags: linux, files, find, sort

Trying to find files that contains specific strings in name, but don't know how to sort output, in a way, that I will get file names only.

I've tried

```
OLDDATA=`find . -regex ".*/[0-9.]+" | ls -t`
```

But ls -t is not working on find result but on whole directory

edit: Result of this statement should be sorted by modification day directories. This regex suppose to match directories that contains only numbers and dots in name.

Comment: May I suggest that you explain what you think that regular expression - ".*/[0-9.]+"  - should match?

Comment: This should match files that contains only numbers and dots in name

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> get file names only ... sorted by modification day

**`find`** + **`sort`** + **`cut`** approach:

```
find . -regex ".*/[0-9.]+" -printf "%T@ %f\n" | sort | cut -d' ' -f2
```

---

- `%T@` - File's last modification time, where `@` is *seconds* since `Jan. 1, 1970, 00:00 GMT,` with fractional part
- `%f` - File's name with any leading directories removed (only the last element)

---

To sort in descending order:

```
find . -regex ".*/[0-9.]+" -printf "%T@ %f\n" | sort -k1,1r | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Comment: The good ol' Schwartzian transform

Comment: Is there option to sort them from the newest? It worked very well, but need dates DESC

Comment: @harcotlupus, see my update

Comment: If I run this on Debian 11 I will only get lines that look like this: `02265526.0`

Answer (score 5):

Your method can be adapted to work in simple cases. The main problem you're facing is that you're passing *input* to `ls`, but `ls` doesn't take any input. `ls` takes command line arguments. So you need to pass the output of `find` as *arguments* to `ls`, with a command substitution. Also, in case a directory is matched, pass `-d` to `ls` to list the directory itself and not its contents.

```
OLDDATA=$(ls -td $(find . -regex ".*/[0-9.]+"))
```

Only in simple cases, because there are two restrictions:

1. This relies on an [unquoted command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) (and so does the use of `$OLDDATA` afterwards). Therefore it assumes that the file names don't contain any special characters (whitespace or wildcard characters `\[*?`).
2. Some versions of `ls` may mangle characters that are not printable in the current locale.
3. If the total length of the file names is too long, you'll get an error. (Note that `find … -exec` and `xargs` cannot help here, since `ls` must run a single time to get the order of the file names right. All they could do is hide errors and produce output that is not correctly sorted — and mangle a few more characters, in the case of `xargs`.)

A robust, simple way of doing this is to use [zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell). It has the ability to sort wildcard matches, thanks to [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers).

```
setopt extended_glob
OLDDATA=(**/[0-9.]##(om))
```

- Since this doesn't call any other program, there is no length limit other than available memory, and no risk of file name mangling at any point.
- The result is a *list* of strings (each string being a file name), not a string, so it goes into an array variable.
- `**/` traverses subdirectories recursively, avoiding the use of `find`.
- `##` means “one or more of the preceding” in zsh extended glob syntax, it's analogous to `+` in (extended) regex syntax.
- `(om)` is a glob qualifier to sort files by modification time, like `ls -t`.

There is notoriously no simple way to do this robustly with POSIX tools or even with GNU tools and ksh.